# 2 pc with same timezone, but javascript returns different offset

Tags: javascript, timezone, offset

I have 2 laptops A(windows server 2008 R2 enterprise) and B(windows 7 ultimate), both are using timezone (UTC+12:00)Fiji.

I have one file Tz.html with below js:

```
var tmSummer = new Date(Date.UTC(2005, 6, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0));
var so = -1 * tmSummer.getTimezoneOffset();
var tmWinter = new Date(Date.UTC(2005, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0));
var wo = -1 * tmWinter.getTimezoneOffset();
alert(so+' '+wo);
```

I put Tz.html on both laptops, then access it locally via IE.

The popup window on laptop A says: "720 720"
But the popup window on B says: "720 780"

Any clues?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you absolutely sure both set to same timezone? maybe one of them automatically switched to daylight savings while other did not...

Comment: @Banana yes, and i can see that these 2 laptops have same time now. currently, both are 6:39 pm

Comment: actually my bad, it has nothing to do with current time as you created a date object for 2005, try splitting the statement to 2 date creation statements and see if on both laptops same date is generated

Comment: @Banana sorry, which statement should be splitted?

Comment: the one which produces the difference, `var tmWinter = new Date(Date.UTC(2005, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0));` split it to `var UTC_Date =   Date.UTC(2005, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0)` and `var tmWinter = new Date(UTC_Date)` and alert/debug both steps on both laptops to see if the date is being changed in any step

Comment: @Banana, the UTC_Date on both laptops are same: 1138579200000, the tmWinter on A is "Mon Jan 30 12:00:00 UTC+1200 2006", but on B it's "Mon Jan 30 13:00:00 UTC+1300 2006", this is quite confusing..

Comment: i think one of them is set to automatically adjust for daylight savings and therefore changes it for that date, check your pc settings see if one of them set to adjust automatically

Comment: @Banana the checkbox "Automatically adjust clock for Daylight Saving Time" is selected on both laptops.